# Why can't I get result from camera intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

This is really strange. My code works fine on one device (MOTO G5S with Android 7) but doesn't on another one (Galaxy S9 with Android 9).

I want to take a picture and this is my code for that:

```
private void takePicture(int file_id) {

    camFileId = file_id;

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
    File file = new File(wrkDir + currFullImageDir + "/" + file_id + ConstValues.IMG_FILE_EXTENSION);
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, ConstValues.CAM_REQEST_CODE);
}
```

Starting Camera Intent works on both devices. But on the MOTO G5S, when a picture is taken, there is a button to accept or discard the picture. On the S9, there is nothing like this. When a picture is taken, the camera intent does not return at all. If the back button is pressed, it returns but within the `onActivityResult(..)` my data is null (of course).

Am I doing anything wrong or is there anything especial for the S9?

Comment: [`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is not very reliable](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/08/action-image-capture-fallacy.html), and `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE` is likely to have similar results.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for the linked post. Any idea if there are solutions for the S9? I don't need it for all kind of devices because it is my private project.

Comment: In that case, try a third-party camera app, and see if it behaves better for you.

Comment: I'm using the camera api now. I think, it's more reliable.